# Not able to reset ionic input ref

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I have an input ref:

```
const titleRef = useRef<HTMLIonInputElement>(null)
```

that I cant seem to reset:

```
const editedTitle = titleRef.current?.value;
titleRef.current.value = "";
```

I'm told by typescript "Object is possibly 'null'." so I'm using a ! after current.
But it doesn't reset the input field anyway.

Note that this is a special input component from the Ionic React library:
[Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input)

It has a clearInput prop, that you can set to ={true}.
That didn't work either, so I hope you have some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your ref mutable:

```
titleRef<HTMLIonInputElement | null>(null)
```

then:

```
if (titleRef.current) titleRef.current = ""
```

Comment: this does not work, unfortunately, not even when adding .value after titleRef.current

Comment: Still the same error? Maybe you need to use useState instead of useRef

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.

take a look at the element:

```
<IonInput clearOnEdit clearInput={true} ref={titleRef} value={input} placeholder={props.editedGoal?.text}
                                              onIonChange={e => setInput(e.detail.value!)}>{}</IonInput>
```

`value={input}` needed to be reset with `setInput("")`